# Powershell - Checking Security Group Members against another list

Tags: powershell

A bit of context, I am trying to get a list of users from a security group, then check if any of those users **do not** have an assigned XenDesktop.

Please forgive me, I only started using Powershell yesterday so my formatting is off. It first grabs the users from the AD group then checks if that user has an assigned desktop, which works but I what I can't seem to get working is that if the user is found in that list, I want it to move onto the next username, instead it continues to check against every machine and then onto the final bits of code.

```
$checkusernames = Get-ADGroupMember "***AD security Group***" | Select SamAccountName

$desktops = get-brokerdesktop -DesktopGroupName Personal_WIN8 | Select MachineName, @{Name='AssociatedUserNames';Expression={[string]::join(“;”, ($_.AssociatedUserNames))}}

foreach ($username in $checkusernames.SamAccountName) {
foreach ($desktop in $desktops) {
If ($desktop.AssociatedUserNames -like "*$username*") {
write-host $username "is assigned to" $desktop.machinename
}
write-host $username "is not assigned to a desktop"
}
Write-host $username "is not assigned to anything"
pause
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to exit from a `ForEach` loop early you can do so with the `Break` keyword. For example:

```
$checkusernames = Get-ADGroupMember "***AD security Group***" | Select SamAccountName

$desktops = get-brokerdesktop -DesktopGroupName Personal_WIN8 | Select MachineName, @{Name='AssociatedUserNames';Expression={[string]::join(“;”, ($_.AssociatedUserNames))}}

foreach ($username in $checkusernames.SamAccountName) {

    $machine = ''

    foreach ($desktop in $desktops) {

        If ($desktop.AssociatedUserNames -like "*$username*") { 
            $machine = $desktop.machinename
            break
        }
    }

    If ($machine) {
        write-host $username "is assigned to" $desktop.machinename
    } Else {
        write-host $username "is not assigned to a desktop"
        pause
    }
}
```

This will stop the current cycle of the inner `ForEach` loop (once it has completed in it's entirety) without interrupting the ongoing cycle of the outer one.

Per the dicussion in the comments, i've also reorganised the code so that you only get a single output dependent on whether a desktop is matched to a user or not and it only pauses if it does not find a match.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I tried the break but it's then moving onto the

     Write-host $username "is not assigned to anything"
     pause

then does another loop.

I want to run the loop until it finds a user that isn't found against the $desktop variable

Comment: Ah ok, so it's ending the current loop cycle, but you want to exit immediately. I think the best workaround for that would just be to use an if..else , i'll amend my answer.

Comment: Oh wait, sorry I misunderstood. Let me rethink.

Comment: Check out the revised answer, let me know if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you! That works brilliantly, I hadn't thought of doing it that way, thanks gain.